# Symfony Send email in production environment

Tags: symfony, sendmail, production-environment, swiftmailer

I am trying to send email in prod environment but it doesn't work... I am getting this log:

> [2014-06-30 09:37:54] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Swift_TransportException: "Expected response code 250 but got code
>   "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
>   o2sm28357522wia.16 - gsmtp "" at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\UniDocs\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
>   line 386 {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException: Expected
>   response code 250 but got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.0 Must
>   issue a STARTTLS command first. o2sm28357522wia.16 - gsmtp\r\n\" at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\UniDocs\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386)"}
>   []

However, in dev it is working...

The config I have is the following:

**config_dev.yml:**

swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:      smtp.gmail.com
    username:  myemail@gmail.com
    password:  mypass

**config.yml:**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
```

**parameters.yml:**

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: myemail@gmail.com
mailer_password: mypass
```

I also have another question..., in web/app.php do I have to write `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` or `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`??

Comment: use mailer_transport: gmail :) -- false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used my Gmail account to send emails in Symfony2, and I specify some parameters which you have not specified. Below is my configuration:

**config.yml:**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
    auth_mode:  %mailer_auth_mode%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_username%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

**parameters.yml:**

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_username: myusername@gmail.com
mailer_password: mypassword
```

Related with your second question, the original line is

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

If you change this to true, error messages can be showed in production mode, because the second parameter of the AppKernel construct indicates the debug mode.

Comment: You can only use 3 parameters -- [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html)

Comment: great @Airam!!!! thanks a lot for your help!! I have spent many hours testing many other configurations that didn't work... yours is perfect!

Comment: You're welcome @bamalu. I'd appreciate if you tick the answer as valid, and in this way, this will be useful for other people with the same problem.

Comment: Works for me with mailer_encryption set to tls, i.e. mailer_encryption: tls