# I can't send email on production environment

Tags: php, symfony, email, production-environment, swiftmailer

I'm working in a symfony project (version 2.3.35) and I can't send emails in the production environment. Mails are sent perfectly in others environments except in production environment.

For instance, when I send an email by command line:
this work:

```
php app/console swiftmailer:email:send --env=dev
```

But, this doesn't work:

```
php app/console swiftmailer:email:send --env=prod
```

The result is the same for both:

```
From: from_email@gmail.com
To: my_email@gmail.com
Subject: lorem ipsum
Body: lorem ipsum
Sent 1 emails
```

But with --env=prod option I don't get any email.

I've tried by setting the parameters.yml and config.yml hundred of times like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485209/symfony-send-email-in-production-environment), but it's still not working.

**app/config/config.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_username%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

**app/config/parameters.yml**

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_username: my_email@gmail.com
mailer_password: apswd
```

Besides:

- The prod.log and dev.log don't have any errors about swiftmailer.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
On the server where the project is stored (Ubuntu Server 12.04), I can send emails using the command line or by using a script php (with mail() function). Both work perfectly.

**THE SOLUTION**

I finally solved the problem by using:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I don't know why, but this command has solved the problem. After this command the emails were sent perfectly from production environment.

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Have you checked with your host? They May be blocking your emails.

Comment: In the host, the mails are sent only in dev or test environment. I only have problems in prod environment

Comment: +1 for this question, I have also been experiencing similar strange issues of late, love to hear the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Mails are sent perfectly in others environments except in production environment.`

Try logging into the production server(s) and attempt to send an email from the command line.

You may need to work with the sysadmins to see if sending email is allowed from production systems.

You may need to work with the security/networking folks to see if the email port (typically port 25) is blocked.